# Load Ad Asynchronously

Tags: flutter, dart, ads

I want to load Ad to my screen and I got Ads as expected but the problem is that **it will make my app slows** since there is many items to load.

- **I want to** load Ads asynchronously, like the other items should first then the Ads. I have pasted my code below, I have put the ad in a container

  ```
  static  Widget cinemaView(AsyncSnapshot<List<CinemaModel>> snapshot) {
  return Column(
     children: <Widget>[
     Expanded(
      child: Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    new MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) =>
                            CinemaNewsDetails(id: snapshot.data[index].id)));
              },
              child: Card(
                elevation: 2.0,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0, bottom: 4.0),
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                    child: snapshot.data[index].image.isNotEmpty
                                        ? Image.network(
                                            snapshot.data[index].image,
                                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                            height: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                    .size
                                                    .height /
                                                8,
                                            width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                    .size
                                                    .width /
                                                4,
                                          )
                                        : Image.network(
                                            'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/zUofRpElgAioazdFZyPTybX3JKFmuBGS0Z0gPR6xuVm3V9f3xGmpUsdTWzNujJWWc5yq',
                                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                          ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                                child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                                    child: Text(snapshot.data[index].title,
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                        maxLines: 3,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: 5.0, left: 8.0),

                                    child: Text(dateEngine(
                                        snapshot.data[index].publishdate)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ))
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
    ),
  ),
  StreamBuilder<Object>(
    stream: null,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return


       Container(
        child:  AdmobBanner(
          adSize: AdmobBannerSize.FULL_BANNER,
          adUnitId: unitId,
        ),
      );
    }
  ),
  ],
  );
  }
  ```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: If you are using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob), they should already be loading async as far as I can tell. If you look into the documentation, they are all futures. Operations also tend to load slower when in debug mode, try running a release maybe?

Comment: i am using https://pub.dev/packages/admob_flutter

Comment: Maybe try changing to the one I linked, as it is developed by the Flutter team. I used this in my app, and had no problems. Should be a smooth transition.

Comment: Did you get this fixed?

Comment: not yet solved.